# Define the polynomial ring $\Bbb Q[c][x]$.Find the $c$ values where $x^2 + x + c + 1$ has a double root.

Tags: computer-science, sagemath

**Sage question:**
Define the polynomial ring $\Bbb Q[c][x]$.Find the $c$ values where $x^2 + x + c + 1$ has a double root.
Sage code I have used.

```
K.<c>=QQ['c']

R.<x>=K[]

f=x^2+x+c+1

f
```

How do I find the code for the $c$ values where $x^2 + x + c + 1$ has a double root. Also, can you give some examples so that I can construct some programming code in sage?

Comment: complete the square:  $x^2+x+\dfrac14=\left(x+\dfrac12\right)^2$

Comment: $c$ is an indeterminate in the polynomial ring $\Bbb Q[c]$. Or is $c%$ for you a complex number? Or do you accept to set $c=-x-1$? Then the polynomial has a double root.

Comment: @DietrichBurde $c$ is a complex number.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner we have to find it using Sage. So I want a code/command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (general) **discriminant** of a polynomial is the resultant of the polynomial with its derivative. It tells you if there are common factors between them, that is the case if and only if it is zero. Common factors here indicate (irreducible) factors of the polynomial with a non-trivial multiplicity.

In https://sagecell.sagemath.org/ this works

```
K.<c>=QQ['c']
R.<x>=K[]
f=x^2+x+c+1
d=f.discriminant(); print d;
d.roots()
```

with the output

```
-4*c - 3
[(-3/4, 1)]
```

Note that the `roots()` output is a list of pairs of root and multiplicity. This approach only works if there are solutions `c` that are in the basis field, here $\Bbb Q$. In other cases, you can proceed to find irreducible factors of the discriminant and from there get some semi-numeric representations of the roots as algebraic numbers (enclosing intervals, Thom sign sequences), or determine numerical approximations of the roots.

Comment: OK, now i see it. The user has to know now that the one in the final result is the multiplicity. And note that with an other `f`, for instance `x^2 + x + c^2 + 1`, the code would produce no answer. (This comment is following comments from the "duplicate post" https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3304492/how-do-i-find-the-code-for-the-c-values-where-x2-x-c-1-has-a-double-r/3304519?noredirect=1#comment6798931_3304519 )

Comment: Thanks, everyone can you please upvote my question and the earlier one. I got many unnecessary comments before you helped me all. Actually, with 23 reputations, I was nowhere to start bounty for those questions. So I had to repost the question.