# How do I find the code for the $c$ values where $x^2 + x + c + 1$ has a double root?

Tags: computer-science, dynamic-programming, programming, sagemath

> **Sage question:**
>   Define the polynomial ring $\Bbb Q[c][x]$.Find the $c$ values where $x^2 + x + c + 1$ has a double root.

Sage code I have used to answer the first part "Define the polynomial ring $\Bbb Q[c][x]$".

```
K.<c>=QQ['c']    
R.<x>=K[]

f=x^2+x+c+1    
f
```

How do I find the code for the $c$ values where $x^2 + x + c + 1$ has a double root? Also, can you give some examples so that I can construct some programming code in sage?

**P.S: This is a sage question. I know that for $c=-\frac 34$ this will be a square but I want the command that I can run in Sage to get this result in Sage. I asked it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3303595/define-the-polynomial-ring-bbb-qcx-find-the-c-values-where-x2-x-c) but got the downvotes and I don't know why! If someone will downvote me here then please explain to me what do I have to include. I have given a code that I used to answer the first part "Define the polynomial ring $\Bbb Q[c][x]$", so this is my try.**

Comment: I don't work with Sage. But the mathematics behind this question are : eliminate $x$ between the equations $p(x)=0$ and $p'(x)=0$ (Nec. and Suf. condition for $x$ to be a double root) ; it remains to "translate" it into Sage.

Comment: Yeah, can you give me a command for that in Sage?

Comment: @RobertZ I have given the link there. And I don't know why am I getting downvotes?

Comment: The first question has no downvotes. Go back and edit the first question, explaining your needs. This question has downvotes because it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question regarding the values of $c$ that make $f$ have double roots is solved for my taste via:

```
sage: R.<x,c> = PolynomialRing(QQ)
sage: f = x^2 + x + c + 1
sage: f.discriminant(x)
-4*c - 3
```

There is no need to have explicitly an equation now, solve it, get the one value. Well, if this not needed complication step is needed, then note that solve is not the method to be used now. We are inside a polynomial ring, the last line, the result `-4*c - 3` has parent

```
sage: f.discriminant(x).parent()
Multivariate Polynomial Ring in x, c over Rational Field
```

and `solve` is properly used in the world of expressions. To see the difference, one would have now to introduce

```
sage: var('X,C');
sage: f(X,C)
X^2 + C + X + 1
sage: f.discriminant(x)(X,C)
-4*C - 3
sage: solve( f.discriminant(x)(X,C) == 0, C )
[C == (-3/4)]
```

to see the last line explicitly.

The second question, "Can you give..." has the answer "Yes, i can". Take a look at the introductions in [sage](https://www.sagemath.org), for instance:

[http://sagebook.gforge.inria.fr/ :: Sagebook, Calcul mathématique avec sage](http://sagebook.gforge.inria.fr/)

or the many books / publications on

http://www.sagemath.org/library-publications.html, there is also a Books session.

---

Later EDIT, 
an lternative solution, as suggested by 
[LutzL](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/115115/lutzl), and discussion.

We use the nested structure as in the post.

```
sage: R.<c> = QQ[]
sage: S.<x> = R[]
sage: ( x^2 + x + c + 1 ).discriminant().roots(multiplicities=0)
[-3/4]
```

The result gives us the impression that everything went fine. To see what may have wrong, consider the code in a slightly different situation:

```
sage: ( x^2 + x + c^3 + 2 ).discriminant().roots(multiplicities=0)
[]
```

Here we have an empty result, have still to look at the intermediate point,

```
sage: ( x^2 + x + c^3 + 2 ).discriminant()
-4*c^3 - 7
```

and realize that the discriminant (built w.r.t. $x$, because of the correct order of nesting, a thing that we always have to think twice when things "go wrong") is a polynomial in $c$ without roots in $\Bbb Q$. So i am more or less determined to consider the "intermediate result" of the polynomial in $c$ as the object to be studied further. Or just use an expression in a *variable* `C`, and solve for `C` explicitly,

```
sage: var('C');
sage: for sol in solve( ( x^2 + x + c^3 + 2 ).discriminant()(C) == 0, C ):
....:     print sol
....:     
C == 1/8*4^(2/3)*(I*7^(1/3)*sqrt(3)*(-1)^(1/3) - 7^(1/3)*(-1)^(1/3))
C == 1/8*4^(2/3)*(-I*7^(1/3)*sqrt(3)*(-1)^(1/3) - 7^(1/3)*(-1)^(1/3))
C == 1/4*7^(1/3)*4^(2/3)*(-1)^(1/3)
sage:
```

Many times i got problems when using nested structures in sage. (Here it works, and it has the didactical advantage of fixing $\Bbb Q[c][x]=\Bbb Q[c,x]$.) And in fact, i am expecting in the computation of the discriminant w.r.t. $x$ in the other solution that the result is in $\Bbb Q[c]$, by structure. The sage implementation uses still the big ring.

Comment: The nested ring structure as used in the question automatically implements the qualitative distinction of parameter and variable, so that `f` is univariate in `x`, and `f.discriminant()` is univariate in `c`. This avoids the necessity of giving hints like here in the multivariate setup.

Comment: This is a matter of taste, i will insert "the other code" using nested structures, and the other discussion. The nested structure brings often problems in sage. (Usually, the second nested polynomial ring has not all properties of the polynomial ring over a field. It is a luck that in the particular case, the particular way to approach using nested polynomial ring works better.)

Comment: Well, as the sage interface seems modeled on the Magma interface, you would for the more general cases have to define the first as function field over `c`. // I already had my variant in an answer to the original question https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3304531/115115

Comment: Thanks, everyone can you please upvote my question and the earlier one. I got many unnecessary comments before you helped me all. Actually, with 23 reputations, I was nowhere to start bounty for those questions. So I had to repost the question.